# PHP Regular Expression: could not convert space into glue

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, whitespace

I have a PHP functions that should do following tasks:
The function will take 2 params - the string and the glue(defaults to "-").
for a given string,
-- remove any special characters
-- make it lowercase
-- remove multiple spaces
-- replace spaces with glue (-).

The function takes $input as parameter. The code I have used for that is below:

```
         //make all the charecters in lowercase
         $low = strtolower($input);

         //remove special charecters and multiple spaces
         $nospecial = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s+]/', '', $low);

         //replace the spaces into glues (-). here is the problem.
         $converted = preg_replace('/\s/', '-', $nospecial);


         return $converted;
```

I did not find anything wrong with this code. but is shows multiple glues in the output. but i have already removed multiple spaces in the second line of the code. so why it shows multiple glues? could anyone have any solution?

Comment: Sorry...it does not work.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but i have already removed multiple spaces in the second line of the code

No, you haven't remove the spaces. The second line of code keeps in `$nospecial` the letters, the digits, the spaces and the plus sign (`+`).

A [character class](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) matches a single character in the subject. `\s+` in a character class doesn't mean "one or many space characters". It means either a space character (`\s`) or a plus sign (`+`). If it would mean what you meant, `$nospecial` won't contain any space character at all.

I suggest you split the second processing step in two: first remove all the special characters (keep letters, digits and spaces) then compact the spaces (there is no way to do both of them in a single replace).

The compacting can be then combined with the replacement of the spaces with the glue in a single operation:

```
 // Make all the charecters lowercase
 // Trim the white spaces first to avoid the final result have stray hyphens on the sides
 $low = strtolower(trim($input));

 // Remove special characters (keep letters, digits and spaces)
 $nospecial = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s]/', '', $low);

 // Compact the spaces and replace them with the glue
 $converted = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $nospecial);

 return $converted;
```

**Update:** added trimming the input string before any processing to avoid getting a result that start or end with the glue. This is not required by the question, it was suggested by @niet-the-dark-absol in a comment and I also think it's a good thing; most probably, the string generated this way is used as file name by the question's author.

Comment: Consider adding `trim($converted,'-')` to remove any stray hyphens on the sides.

Comment: You're making the same mistake @HamZA did in his comment.  With the `\s` removed from the first regex, all whitespace will be deleted in that step.

Comment: Hey...your code works well... i have changed a liitl bit of your code. I have putted a "s" on the second line of the code like below:
$nospecial = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', $low);
now it works properly. Thanks :)  @axiac

Comment: My words said something but my code said the opposite. My bad :-)

Comment: @AlanMoore you are right, I wrote *"keep letters, digits and spaces"* in the answer but forgot about the spaces in the code. Thank you.

Comment: @HamZa thank you for the addition of `\s` into the regexp. The removal of `A-Z` also makes sense; the string was converted to lowercase in the previous statement. Maybe it's time for me to go to sleep, to avoid misleading others with my answers :-)